# Microservice test automation validation of optional fields

Tags: automated-tests, integration-testing, microservices, end-to-end, pact

I am currently working on function test automation of micro-services for appointment scheduling system for retail orders. We have service A which calls service B using an adapter with customer details ,order number, agent id (optional).Service B returns a response of available date and time slot . However there are 2 scenarios of scheduling

1) Service B can return slots of specific agent if agent id is passed to it from service A 
2)Service B can return slots of all agents if agent id is not passed.

Now I want to validate below scenario:
When I pass the agent id to body of service A, the adapter should pass it while calling service B.

Is there a way I can test if the adapter has passed correct request to service B. I looked at Pact for contract test but since reponse is same in both cases, I couldn't figure out how we can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "adapter", but I'm guessing it's the client class in the Service A codebase that is responsible for making the HTTP requests to Service B. If that is so, I believe your question is "can I check that the adapter passes the agent ID parameter to Service B in the request". The answer is yes - that's exactly what you are doing when you write the request expectation in a Pact consumer test.

The 'withRequest' is the part of the test where you define what the expected request is:

```
const interaction = {
        state: "i have a list of cats",
        uponReceiving: "a request for cats with given catId",
        withRequest: {
          method: "GET",
          path: "/cats",
          query: {
            "catId[]": Matchers.eachLike("1"),
          },
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
          },
        },
        willRespondWith: {
          status: 200,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: EXPECTED_BODY,
        },
      }
```

[https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/blob/058ab6f63e4273b545761e82cd3d9a1ae4f72bb6/examples/jest/**tests**/catAPI.spec.js#L17-L26](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/blob/058ab6f63e4273b545761e82cd3d9a1ae4f72bb6/examples/jest/__tests__/catAPI.spec.js#L17-L26)

Comment: This definitely addresses the scenario where service A is  making a HTTP call to Service B and optional fields are not part of Pact configuration. Let me elaborate on the scenario I am looking to address by taking an example. Lets assume Service A accepts 3(id, name,phone)  parameters in POST body and it  calls Service B after validating the input. Out of the 3 parameters  phone is optional. So if phone number is passed to service A, then service A should pass phone number  to service B . If it doesn't then it's a violation of contract. Can Pact help address this scenario?